# Why does the Well Ordering Theorem imply decreasing ordinals go to zero?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

The Well Ordering Theorem states that any set can be well ordered. But in [this PBS Infinite Series video](https://youtu.be/uWwUpEY4c8o?t=483), Kelsey states the theorem as, "Any decreasing sequence of ordinals eventually goes to zero." This isn't an obvious equivalence to me. Does deeper work need to be done to prove it, or is it a one-liner?

It may be hard for me to see the connection because I don't know the rigorous definition of ordinals, just the intuitive idea from the above-linked episode.

Comment: As stated it's not true.  The sequence $(3, 2, 1)$ obviously doesn't go to $0$.  A correct statement would be that an infinite decreasing sequence of ordinals cannot be strictly decreasing and eventually must stabilize.

Comment: That's a good point, or how about: A strictly decreasing list of ordinals $(a_i)$ with the property that "$a_i\neq 0\Rightarrow a_{i+1}$ exists" must have finite length and end with $a_N = 0$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sequence is decreasing, it has to be finite, since a well-ordering does not have any infinitely decreasing sequences. But that means that we have to stop somewhere, and if you take "decreasing" to mean "continue to decrease as long as you can" that means that the last element of the sequence must be the minimum, i.e. $0$.

Comment: Why does a well ordering not have any infinitely decreasing sequences? The interval $[0,\infty)$ has a least element and also contains many infinitely decreasing sequences. I know this doesn't disprove your assertion, but I'm just showing why I don't find it obvious.

Comment: Having a minimum is not the same as being well-ordered. If $\{a_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a decreasing sequence, can you tell me what is the smallest element of that set?

Comment: Right, I agree $[0,\infty)$ is not well ordered (under the usual ordering of reals). I just don't see why a well-ordering can't have any infinitely decreasing subsequences.

Comment: I asked you a question, that should lead you to this understanding.

Comment: Ok, now I see it.

Comment: Ok on further reflection, I am confused about something else. It seems your argument applies just as well to the reals as to the ordinals. The WOT says *any* set can be well ordered, which means $\mathbb R$ has some well ordering (though of course not the typical ordering we're used to).

Comment: The fact that our statement about sequences *doesn't* apply to $\mathbb R$ (with the usual ordering) relies on the fact that $\mathbb R$ with the usual ordering is *not* a well ordering. So to prove the claim about sequences of ordinals terminating at zero, don't we need to prove that the standard ordering (of ordinals) *is* also a well-ordering?

Comment: That's generally clear from the standard definition of ordinals because $\cap \{ \alpha_i \}$ is the least element of any set of ordinals $\{ \alpha_i \mid i \in I \}$.

Comment: @WillG: Yes, and it is. That is one of the first things we prove about well-orders: given two well-orders, one is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other (perhaps the whole order). And if you take a von Neumann ordinals as "the ordinals", then they are by definition transitive sets that are well-ordered by $\in$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok thanks, I don’t know enough about ordinals, but this sounds reasonable. Can you recommend any good sources for a rigorous introduction to ordinals?

Comment: @WillG: Not off the top of my head. But any decent basic book about set theory should develop the basics of ordinals. You can look at the set theory notes in my website, it might not be the best source, since it was meant for my students back in Jerusalem who already studied the very basics of ordinals before, but it might help you get some idea...

Answer (score 1):

Let $(E,<)$ be a well ordered set.

Suppose for contradiction that there is an infinite decreasing sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $E$.
Since $E$ is well ordered, the set $X:=\{x_n \big| \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has a minimum, say $m$.
For every $x\in X$, the set $\{y\in X \big| \ x<y\}$ has a minimum, we hence have a function $S : X \mapsto X, \ x \mapsto \min\big(\{y\in X \big| \ x<y\}\big)$. $S$ behaves like a *successor function* : there is no $y\in X$ such that $x<y<S(x)$.

The function $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \mapsto X, \ n \mapsto S^n(m)$ is an order-isomorphism.
The sequence $(\sigma^{-1}(x_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of elements of $\mathbb{N}$, an absurdity!

Comment: I wonder if this proof might be more convoluted than necessary, but I appreciate the rigor. However, I'm still worried that my concern in comments #6 & 7 from the other answer (about this argument also applying to $\mathbb R$) is also left unanswered by this proof.